# What's the fastest way to open up .vimrc?

Tags: vimrc

I'm just getting into Vim, and, as one might expect, I'm constantly adding things to my `.vimrc`. At the moment i'm using `:tabe ~/.vimrc` and I was just curious if there was a quicker command for getting to the`.vimrc` that was used when Vim launched.

Comment: Not quicker, but thought you should know, `:e $MYVIMRC`. And, many people create a keybinding for editing their `vimrc`. You could also do that, especially if you're at the beginning of your vim journey and constantly editing your `vimrc`.

Comment: With tabcompletion `:e $MYV<Tab><CR>`. However, I would certainly recommend using the uppercase mark `'V` for this as Matt showed in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `$MYVIMRC`. See `:help .vimrc`. It says:

> The $MYVIMRC environment variable is set to the file that was first found, 
>   unless $MYVIMRC was already set and when using VIMINIT.

`$MYVIMRC` is also not set if you use the command line option `-u` to specify a different ini file.

I have two mappings in my `vimrc`:

```
noremap _v :e $MYVIMRC<CR>
noremap _u :source $MYVIMRC<CR>
```

By hitting `_v` I can open my `vimrc` and with `_u` the `vimrc` is reloaded.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use a bookmark.

That is, while `.vimrc`is open, press <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to save current position in a global bookmark 'V'. To reopen `.vimrc` in the current window simply go to the bookmark with <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

The "capital letters" bookmarks are automatically saved in `viminfo`, so they will persist between sessions. Also, there are 26 such bookmarks, so you can easily track a couple of other important files, not just `.vimrc`.

Comment: +1 It took me an embarrassingly long time to discover how useful uppercase marks are for this sort of thing. (Literally years.) Sidenote: if there are 26 bookmarks, you can track up to 25 other files, not just a couple! ;)

Comment: @Rich Well, it took me significantly less time, though I didn't discover it myself, but saw this advice somewhere ;-)